# Reusing try/except for different parameters in a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a function having a try/except block for 5 parameters:

```
def clarifythis(dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4, dict5):
    try:
      Process dict1
    except Exception:
      Process dict1 differently
```

For those 5 params, should I write 5 different blocks for try/except or employ a for loop :

```
def clarifythis(dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4, dict5):
    for i in (dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4, dict5):   
        try:
         Process i
        except Exception:
         Process i differently
```

Reason for asking - Never used a try/except statement, hence clarifying this.

Comment: Actually you can do both but 2nd is much shorter.

Comment: why would you expect the behavior to be different when doing the for loop, rather than writing it out and repeating x times.

Comment: @Alderven - Nice, will go ahead with the 2nd one.

Comment: @BlueRineS - I saw try/except videos on youtube, but nothing got into my head, I thought I must ask before trying anything with try/except. Delft university is my dream one, I hope I get into it, so happy to talk to someone who studied from it.

Comment: Good luck with your applications then ;)

Comment: @BlueRineS: Thank you, Sir. Hope that you reach new heights as an R&D engineer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending what you want and think about what exceptions you can have from start:
you can have also something like that:

```
def clarifythis(dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4, dict5):
    try:
      Process dict1
    except Exception.name1:
      Process dict1 differently
    except Exception.name2:
      Process dict1 differently
    ...
```

and from my experience I did not meet to process more than 2-3 params, and dict??? by dict you mean dictionary?Also if you add here an for loop will be a little bit hard to understand and to see whats going on here!

Comment: Yes, by dict I meant Dictionary. It's actually a function that would process the results of 5 other functions, hence 5 params.

Comment: Won't it be a very long list, if I catch all those exceptions by name. Athough, that's a very nice and new thing to me.

Comment: So think first what exception you can have for all process operation that you want todo, for example if you will have just one exception like when you will have an NoneType dictionary and will try to iterate trough it you will have something like :NoneType object is not iterable, and if this is only one I think you can use for, but in this case more right will be to check dict before iterating, in general try/exception is a little bit complicated theme, and before use it think if this is really necessary.